# Using an external monitor on a lubuntu laptop?

Tags: lubuntu

I'm planning on installing lubuntu on my laptop and buying an external monitor for it. I have 2 questions:

1. Will it work right when I plug it in? I know my nvidia gpu driver will not work by default, so that's why I wonder, is it necessary to have the gpu enabled/working?
2. How do I stop my laptop from going in sleep mode when I close the lid? I want to use my external monitor only, so I want to close the laptop, make sure the laptop screen turns off, but the external monitor has to work.

Thank you very much for any answers. whether I will install lubuntu on my laptop will depend on whether I can or can not use an external monitor.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 : Your Nvidia GPU driver should work by default but it will be using the open source driver by Nouveau. Typically on the Nvidia cards the open source drivers are not as fast as the proprietary drivers provided by Nvidia. However, the drivers by Nouveau tend to be more stable.

Try the open source ones first if you don't get the performance you like then try the Nvidia proprietary ones. To change GPU drivers go into the additional drivers settings.

Question 2 : This just takes some tweaking in the settings. There is usually power settings in every distro that will let you set things like this. For instance set the close lid setting to “do nothing” when you close it. The external should work just fine.